# how to get a JSON array representation of a list of POJOS using codehaus.jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

i've looking for a way to convert to json a list of POJOs.

we've been using `codehaus jackson` already with spring MVC .what i wanted to achieve is not in an ajax call with `@ResponseBody` action, i'm thinking of a util method to convert list of Pojos to json array but after looking at [examples](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonSampleSimplePojoMapper) and  [ObjectMapper class](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.4/javadoc/index.html) it seems there is no straight forward way to achieve it. they have created a class PojoMapper to do that.

```
public static String toJson(Object pojo, boolean prettyPrint)
throws JsonMappingException, JsonGenerationException, IOException {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    JsonGenerator jg = jf.createJsonGenerator(sw);
    if (prettyPrint) {
        jg.useDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    }
    m.writeValue(jg, pojo);
    return sw.toString();
}
```

i'm just wondering it that's the recommended way. on another examples they used a file, but i have no entention to use file but object.So am wondering if anybody can show the way.

thanks for reading this

Comment: Why won't `ObjectMapper` work for you?

Comment: basically am not saying that . i've written: "i'm just wondering it that's the recommended way." because the example i posted from the fasterxml.com doesn't look straight forward considering the number of steps. If that's how it's can you point me to a resource where i can read on how to serialise a list of Pojos to a json array? thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to do the following.

```
List<POJO> list = ...;
String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(list);
```

If you a bidirectional parent/child relationship. Then you need to add annotations to inform Jackson of this relationship.

```
class Parent {

    private Child child;

    @JsonManagedReference
    Child getChild() {return child;}

    void setChild(Child child) {this.child = child;}

}

class Child {

    private Parent parent;

    @JsonBackReference
    Parent getParent() {return parent;}

    void setParent(Parent parent) {this.parent = parent;}        

}
```

The above informs Jackson of the cyclical nature of the relationship and doesn't try to unfold the infinite cycle of references. This works for Jackson 1.6+. I've not had this problem before and I don't have Jackson on this machine and so haven't been able to test this properly.

You should also note that the [documentation](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.6.3/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonBackReference.html) says that the parent cannot be a collection.

Comment: Hello it's throwing an exception org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)(through reference chain: bla.bla.model.ContentImpl["contentFiles"]->org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet[0]->bla.bla.model.FileImpl["content"]-> so on. i used the same same to diplay a table later on an there not problem with the set i think

Comment: Do you have bidirectional relationships between parent and child objects? That is two objects that contain references to each other.